# Changing Label from different views in Objective C / Xcode

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I got an app with one main view and 5 other table views. Selecting row in each table changes some Labels in main view. Is it making main view as delegate of 5 table views right way to choose or there are other more elegant ways? Please, I need just ideas, no code lines. Thanks

Comment: Delegation is a good way to go. Is the data persisted ?

Comment: You can also use NSNotificationCenter to post notifications on your table views status.

Comment: Delegation is more appropriate than notifications in this case (1:1 rather than 1:many distribution), and implementation using blocks is code efficient.

Comment: So it is ok if my mainview has <delegate1, delegate2, ..., delegate5> ?

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if 5 tables will be present in other class. This will separate your code and code complexity will be less.

For labels, just declare one string in app delegate as

```
//in appdelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lblName;

//in appdelegate.m
@synthesize lblName;
```

Then,
In the class where tables are you can acess the label as

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then label text will be set as, `app.lblName=@"Something";`

You can access lblName in any class. Just you have to create share instance of app delegate using which you have to access lblName and other strings which you want to access.

Finaly when you come on the main view you can set the label text as

```
Your_label.text=app.lblName;
```

Comment: I've used 5 TableViewControllers - so different classes for each TableViewController

Comment: It was good. Now use app delegate class to declare the string which will be global and can be accessible in all classes. Using that string set the text of label when you come back from table view controller to main view.